# Proof for the negative definition of a limit as $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x\sin^2(x)+1} $

Tags: limits

this one problem has been tripping me up and I need guidance. I know that the limit doesn't exist because it keeps oscillating between $1$ and a value approaching $0$, however I'm stuck on the last step of my formal proof. I have been able to find that my $x > M, x = \pi k, \epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, and that when $L<0$ and $L=0$ the statement $|f(x)- L| \geq \epsilon$ is true ($1\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for $L = 0$ and $1 + L \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for $L = 0$). However, when $L>0$ the statement is obviously not true. If someone could help guide me (not looking for an explicit answer) that would be very appreciated.

Comment: If $L\gt 0$, pick $\epsilon = \frac{L}{2}$ and find values of $x$ that where $f$ is smaller.

Answer (score 1):

For any $M$, we can take some $x > \max(1, M)$ s.t. $x = 2\pi n + \pi/2$ for some $n$, hence $\frac{1}{x\sin^2(x) +1} = \frac{1}{x +1} \leq \frac{1}{2}$ but also find an $x' > \max(1, M)$ s.t. $x = 2\pi m$ for some $m$, hence $\frac{1}{x\sin^2(x) + 1} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$. Thus if we take $\epsilon = 1/4$, we just showed that there is no $L$ s.t. $f(x) \in (L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon)$ for all $x \geq M$ (since $f(x) \leq 1/2$ and $f(x') =1$ for some $x, x' \geq M$, but $f(x), f(x') \in (L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon) \implies |f(x) - f(x')| < 2\epsilon = 1/2$, but $|f(x) - f(x')| \geq 1/2$, a contradiction).